# Regex to match mixed lower alphanumeric strings

Tags: regex, string, sublimetext3

I'm working with a large document in `Sublime Text 3`, whose Find and Replace feature takes regex. Each string in the document is separated by a line break. I need a regex that will match strings made up of lowercase alphanumeric characters mixed in any order, such as the following:

```
aa0555aaaaf
593dm03ks03
19204f02040
```

After looking into regex, the best I've been able to come up with so far is the below:

```
^[a-z][0-9]{11,}$\n
```

...although this only seems to match strings that start with letters and end in numbers, and for some reason doesn't seem to be case-sensitive either:

```
aa09304030
AA00450354
```

Comment: `(?m-i)^[a-z0-9]{11,}$` where the inline modifier _forces_ multi-line and case sensitive. If your editor isn't totally jacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
^[a-z0-9]{11,}$\n
```

Updated:
Remember to enable "case sensitive"
[image]

Updated:

Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew about the inline modifier of "case insenstive mode"

```
 (?-i)^[a-z0-9]{11,}$\R?
```

Comment: Ditto, ended up getting there a few mins before you posted this and was in the middle of typing up my own answer. This version still isn't case-sensitive though, for some reason.

Comment: I'll make some test

Comment: Is the "case sensitive" disabled?

Comment: It is, but I assumed there was a regex-specific selector for case-sensitivity, just like the "Whole Word" option simply surrounds the regex in `\b`s, and which you can also do manually. I prefer to enter these manually so I can read the whole regex and its behaviour easier.

Comment: A `(?-i)` in line modifier disables case insensitive mode. Try `(?-i)^[a-z0-9]{11,}$\R?`